# Iphone smileys not showing on my android application

Tags: android

When user entered their comments using iphone smileys, the smileys not showing on android device.

I've thinked android does not support iphone smileys.

But in instagram application, the smileys are working well both iphone smilyes and android.

How to achive this?

I'm using below code to decode and encode the string

```
public class Base64Util {

    public static String decodeBase64(String encodedString)
    {

        byte[] byteData = Base64.decode(encodedString, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        String decodedString = null;
        try {
            decodedString= new String(byteData, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return decodedString;
    }

    public static String encodedBase64(String currentString)
    {


        byte[] commentData = null;

        try 
        {
            commentData = currentString.trim().getBytes("UTF-8");           
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        String b =Base64.encodeToString(commentData, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        return b;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution.

i've stored iphone emojis on drawable folder

When u get the string from server like  "This is sample emoji ##emoji001####emoji002##"

u can replace the string  like below

```
.replaceAll("##emoji1f4b8##","<img src=\"smile.png\"/>")
```

Now load the string using

```
Html.fromHtml (String source, Html.ImageGetter imageGetter, Html.TagHandler tagHandler)
```